# Can CircuitBraker design pattern be used with SOAP based web services in java

Tags: java, spring, rest, soap, circuit-breaker

I am new to the Spring cloud environment and i am trying out on implementing the circuit breaker pattern using SOAP based web service...

i implemented circuit breaker with REST and did upload in pivotal cloud foundry.

is that possible to implement it with in SOAP based web services.?

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Hystrix implementation, you can directly add @HystrixCommand annotation on the method you want to monitor (the method that will receive the SOAP request object for example).

In the example provided by Spring : `@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "reliable")`
https://spring.io/guides/gs/circuit-breaker/

Comment: Thank you very much for your response...
I tried the example in the link you mentioned and i am successful in implementing it locally and on pcf..
But that is based on REST service...
Can you share me the link for some examples on circuit breaker implementation in SOAP based web service..??